# MapReduce Sorting on the basis of three fields

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This question is regarding the Map/Reduce sorting. I have three fields

```
XXID, Identifier, TimeStamp
```

The XXID can be any Strings value, the identifier has got two possible values 1 or 2

I want the sorting to be such that all the same XXID goes to the same reducer and in the iterable the fields with 1 comes first in the iterable with increasing timestamp and fields with 2 comes next.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You are definitely violating the mapreduce framework to do this, but you gotta do what you gotta do!

---

First of all, the sorting is only done on the key. Therefore, you have to assume that the values are going to be in an arbitrary order. Therefore, we need to figure out how to get the XXID, Identifier, and TimeStamp, all in the key together. (You can probably just use NullWriteable as the value now)

To fit the three items into a key, you should make a new data type by implementing [WriteableComparable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html). Have this new class wrap the three values and let's call it `JavanxTriple`.

The way you are going to customize the MapReduce sort of `JavanxTriple` items is to change the `.compareTo` function from [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true). Make it so XXID is compared first, then 1 or 2, then the time stamp.

---

Next, you need to solve the problem that since each of these things are separate keys, that by default data will go to different reducers. Out of the box, you won't be able to compute the streams of data that you want. To get around this problem, you need to write a custom [partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html). The partitioner tells which reducer each record is going to go to. In order to do this, you override `.getPartition`. When you are calculating `.getPartition`, only use XXID to determine this number (not the Identifier and TimeStamp portions of the key). They way, all items with the same XXID are sent to the same reducer.

---

Finally, you now have the problem that the way you implement the reducer will not be typical. The reduce will only get called once per key, and the Iterable that gets passed in will only have a NullWriteable in it.

To get around this, use some static variables in the Reducer class to keep track of what is going on in the reduce functions. You have to detect when the XXID changes so you know to switch up the next analysis. You may have to use the [setup and cleanup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html) methods to set things up and finish things up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I was doing and thought that there might be some better solution and it seems this is the work around to do with.
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately as soon as you start breaking out of the mold things get ugly quick

Comment: To sort 100 GB data and other calulations done on it right now its taking 50 mins with 9 data nodes and 216 mappers. Is it considered to be poor performance?

Comment: That does sound a bit on the slow side. There are probably some ways to make it faster. Some things I'd look for: are you using enough reducers? Are there enough map slots and reduce slots in your cluster? You may want to post another question here with some job stats and cluster info.

Comment: 216 Mappers and 70 reducers as far the current configuration